# Displacement definition

Tags: distance, displacement

Is it correct to define the displacement exactly as the shortest distance covered (not necessarily a particular case of the distance covered in this case)? In another way, can it be said that it is a particular case of the physical concept of distance, that is, the case in which the trajectory is straight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture to help:

[image]

Note that displacement is a **vector**, whereas distance is a scalar.

An easy way to think about it is: displacement takes into account only where you started and where you finished, whereas the trajectory is actually how you get from start to finish. The length of that trajectory is the distance.

The length (or magnitude) of the displacement equals the distance if and only if the trajectory is a perfectly straight line.

Comment: Thinking of just the starting and ending position does not guarantee that the magnitude of the displacement is necessarily equivalent to that of a straight line between the two, but still in a way, I think that the notion of vector is equivalent to a straight line, or the smallest distance between two points, for pure intuitive thinking and that is why the idea of the whole concept of displacement makes sense?
In this case, then, does the concept of trajectory have nothing to do with displacement but only with distance, so that this vector design is not an indication of a trajectory?

Comment: @FlávioDorta The magnitude of a vector *is* the length of the vector. If this vector is connecting two points, then the magnitude of the vector is the length between those two points.

Comment: The displacement is simply the change in position of an object. E.g.: If can tell you that I started at point $(1,1)$ (I'm ignoring units), and walked over to point $(2,1)$. Well, my initial position is $(1,1)$ whereas my final position is $(2,1)$. My displacement would then be $(1,0)$. Given my initial or final position and the displacement, you can conclude where I moved from and where I moved to, but you do not know how I got there.

Comment: However, (and this is perhaps more advanced), I could give you a position (or displacement) function ${\bf \vec r}(t)$ which represents the displacement of an object as a function of time. From that function, you can find the distance by calculating $\displaystyle \int_C \| \mathrm d \bf \vec r \|$. The idea is that we take the displacement function, look at infinitesimally tiny displacements $\mathrm d\bf \vec r$, take their magnitude, $\| \mathrm d \bf \vec r \|$, then use the integral to take the sum of these quantities, and end up with the distance.

Comment: BUT, if all you're given is a displacement vector like $\Delta {\bf \vec r} = (1,2,3)\ \rm m$, then all you cannot conclude anything about trajectory from that statement alone.

Answer (score 2):

Usually *displacement* means the *displacement vector*, which points from some initial to a final position. Its magnitude is the euclidian distance between these two locations. The length of the displacement vector coincides with distance if and only if the path follows a straight line. In all other cases, the distance is strictly larger than the magnitude of the displacement vector.

Comment: When you say coincide, it doesn’t imply that it’s a particular case, right? Exactly that is the other part of the doubt, if displacement is a vector it can never be a specific case of distance, this coincidence is just an informal way of thinking, is that right?

Comment: I have changed it to highlight the difference between vectors and scalars. In a strict sense, when we mean the displacement vector, it cannot be equal to the distance, which is a scalar. But, in certain circumstances (straight path), the length of the displacement vector (also a scalar) is equal to the distance.